# Datatype conversion and calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, calculated-columns

I have a table with the following structure:

[image: table]

Unfortunately, the `sale_date` is stored as INT and I had to find a way to convert it in quarter (202001 will be Q1). The conversion worked well, but I need to include also some calculated columns based on this conversion. Basically, I need to calculate for Q1 the total price for each product, and the percentage from total for "product x" and "product y" recorded by each seller, in the current year. I know that I can obtain these easily using group by, but the way I converted the date (`sale_date`) from INT to quarter it's affecting the results.

```sql
SELECT
  seller,
  product_name,
  LEFT([sale_date],4) Year,
  'Q'+ CAST((CAST(RIGHT(sale_date,2) AS INT)-1 )/3 +1 AS varchar) Quarter,
  (price),
  price * 100.0 / sum(price) over () as percentage_total,
  SUM (price) as total_sales
FROM table1
GROUP BY
  LEFT(sale_date,4),
  'Q'+ CAST((CAST(RIGHT(sale_date,2) AS INT) -1 )/3 +1 AS varchar),
  seller,
  product_name,
  price
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** You should always use the right datatype for a column. It will avoid lots of issues. Always store Date values in `date` datatype.

I would suggest you first convert the `INT` to date datatype and then use `DATE` functions to calculate quarter name. It will be accurate.

Below I am adding `01` as the date to the `yyyymm` and then making it as `yyyymmdd`, to make it as [ISO 8601 dateformat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (which is agnostic of dateformats) and then calculating the quarter value.

```sql
declare @table table(sales_date int, product_name varchar(30),seller varchar(30), price int)

insert into @table
VALUES(202001,'Product X', 'Agent1',2320),(202001,'Product X', 'Agent2',1416),
(202004,'Product X', 'Agent1',420)

SELECT seller, product_name,
CONCAT('Q',DATENAME(QUARTER,CONCAT(CAST(sales_date AS VARCHAR(10)),'01'))) as Quarter,
sum(price) as total_sales
from @table
group by seller, product_name,
CONCAT('Q',DATENAME(QUARTER,CONCAT(CAST(sales_date AS VARCHAR(10)),'01')))
```

```
+--------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| seller | product_name | Quarter | total_sales |
+--------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Agent1 | Product X    | Q1      |        2320 |
| Agent1 | Product X    | Q2      |         420 |
| Agent2 | Product X    | Q1      |        1416 |
+--------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```